# Openshift Build Failure - Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: java, openshift, pom.xml, wildfly-8, aerogear

i'm using OpenShift for hosting a WildFly Application Server 8.2.1. Recently i added support for AeroGear to my application through the pom.xml via the following lines:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
  <artifactId>unifiedpush-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Deploying the wildlfy server locally with IntelliJ IDEA is working without any problems.

But when i try to deploy it to my already working application, there is going to happen the following BUILD FAILURE:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project com.example.test: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project 
com.example.test-wildfly:com.example.test-wildfly:war:1.0:  
Failed to collect dependencies for 

[org.jboss.aerogear:unifiedpush-java-client:jar:1.1.0.Final (compile),  
org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.2.1 (compile), 
org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:jar:1.0.1 (compile), 
com.google.guava:guava:jar:10.0.1 (compile), 
javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0 (provided), 
com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-ws:jar:2.5.0 (compile), 
org.json:json:jar:20090211 (compile), 
org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:jar:1.3.0 (compile), 
org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13 (compile), 
org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13 (compile), 
commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9 (compile), 
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 (compile),
org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.3 (compile), 
org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2 (compile),
io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0 (compile), 
io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.1.0 (compile), 
io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlet:jar:3.1.0 (compile)]:

Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3:
Failure to find org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:9 in
http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local
repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus 
has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I already visited http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public, and it seems to be that the jar for org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:9 (http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/9/) is missing there (the jars for the other dependencies are available there).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as of the last 24 hours with a different library.  When I manually try to navigate the nexus repository @  http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/ I'm getting intermittent 500s and redirects to localhost.  It seems like someone at redhat pushed a bad configuration to their servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with one of the three systems behind the load balancer which serves this content.  It should now be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After digging... A lot. I've found that the maven repositories on OpenShift are very heavily broken at the moment.

As a verification you can click the following link and refresh page.  Notice that it will intermittently jump to 500 errors and in some cases display incomplete contents:

http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/9/

Due to the way maven caches failures, once you hit your first HTTP error on their mirror, the maven client will cache that the resource is not available and you will consistently see the same error for 24 hours.

As a temporary work around I've run:

```
rsync -a ~/.m2/repository/ ${OPENSHIFT_SSH_URL}:~/.m2/repository/
```

after cleanly building the code locally

Comment: thanks for your answer, in my case it didn't helped :( when i try to deploy it after i used the rsync command it says: `Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:18`